# SOAPUI ssl intercept

Tags: soapui

Hi I want to parse ssl soap message through `soapUI`, while I am trying to intercept by `HttpMonitor` it is showing below exception

```
ERROR:Exception in request: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message
```

, plaintext connection?

Comment: It is not clear from this question whether soapui or httpmonitor is showing the below exception.  Clarifying that will enable a more precise answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Change protocol in request adress in SOAPui from http to **https**
[image]
also set **keystore** and **keystore password** in soapui preferences

[image: set keystore and keystore password in soapui preferences]

Comment: This answer didn't work for me. By the way, I'm using soapUI 4.5.2.